# A function to convert JSONArray to list of generic type

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I have JSON data form response looks like this

```
{
  "message": "",
  "data" : [...]
}
```

`data` contains an array of

```
data class News(
  @SerializedName("id") val id: Int,
  @SerializedName("title") val title: String,
  @SerializedName("description") val desc: String
)
```

or

```
data class Product(
  @SerializedName("id") val id: Int,
  @SerializedName("name") val name: String
)
```

based on what endpoint I hit.

To obtain the data from json object, I create 2 functions

```
fun JSONObject.toNewsList() = Gson().fromJson<List<News>>(getJSONArray("data").toString(),
    object : TypeToken<List<News>>(){}.type)!!

fun JSONObject.toProductList() = Gson().fromJson<List<Product>>(getJSONArray("data").toString(),
    object : TypeToken<List<Product>>(){}.type)!!
```

Those functions work perfectly until I try to combine them into a function using generic type as the parameter looks like this

```
fun <T> JSONObject.toList() = Gson().fromJson<List<T>>(getJSONArray("data").toString(),
    object : TypeToken<List<T>>(){}.type)!!
```

Whenever I call the function `jsonResponse.toList<News>()`, it always return error `com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.example.News`

Any idea where I went wrong, and how to fix it?

**Edit :**
Every response in my project always received as encrypted string, that's why I have to map the response by myself and can't put the response type in `Call` method. This is my `Call` function looks like

```
@POST("endpoint")
fun service(@Body body: RequestBody): Call<String>
```

Comment: *Any idea where I went wrong* why do you want to genericize this

Comment: @TimCastelijns Actually, it has more objects besides `News` and `Product`. That's why I want to combine the function to shorten my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google gson LinkedTreeMap class cast to myclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32444863/google-gson-linkedtreemap-class-cast-to-myclass)

Comment: What do you use to send request and receive response?

Comment: @faranjit OkHttp using Retrofit2 as REST client. But I'm sure there is no problem with the network process.

Comment: I can recommend you another way kindly similar. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42643073/1595442) out.

Comment: @faranjit Thx for the suggestion, but every request and response in my project always sent as an encrypted string. That's why I have to map the response by my self because I can't put the response type in `Call` method

Comment: Ok, how about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25432197/1595442)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TypeToken.getParameterized` like this:

```
inline fun <reified T> JSONObject.toList(): List<T> {
    val typeToken = TypeToken.getParameterized(List::class.java, T::class.java)
    return Gson().fromJson<List<T>>(json, typeToken.type)!!
}
```

Comment: Nice Solution, this is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your `response` clas should be like below

```
class ResponseList<E> {
  var message:String
  var data:ArrayList<E>
}
```

you can call your `API` like

```
@GET("url")
fun getNews():Call<ResponseList<News>>
```

Comment: Thx for the suggestion, but every request and response in my project always sent as an encrypted string. That's why I can't put the response type in `Call` method.