# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to X error when call to X error when call Gson fromJson for generic type

Tags: java, android, kotlin, generics, gson

Hi I have this code in Kotlin Android
I try to parse JSON string to data clas, but the data is unknown, I mean the data class is genric type T

```
class JsonFeatureFlag<T>(
        key: String,
        @StringRes nameResId: Int,
        category: DevOptionCategory,
        val defaultValue: T
    ): FeatureFlagV2<T>(key, nameResId, category) {
    .....
    override fun getValue(): T {
            val json = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().getString(key)
            return try {
                Gson().fromJson(json, object: TypeToken<T>(){}.type)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                reportInvalidJson(json)
                defaultValue
            }
        }
    ....
    }
```

And I'm getting this error:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to X

While I understand that TypeToken should be used for generic, something isn't working.

Comment: Due to type erasure at runtime the `T` is just `java.lang.Object` (respectively Kotlin's `Any`, I assume). Gson deserializes `Object` by default to a `Map`. If you can change your `JsonFeatureFlag` class to include the runtime class of `T`, then you can directly pass that class to the `Gson.fromJson` call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gson, ClassCastException with Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431859/gson-classcastexception-with-generics)

Comment: thanks @Marcono1234 , I also read regarding the  type erasure.
I have change it to 
Gson().fromJson(json, className)
and I passing the  className: Class<T> to the method

Comment: If that solved your issue, would you mind adding your own answer to this StackOverflow question to indicate that it has been answered?

Comment: hi @Marcono1234  I sow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431859/gson-classcastexception-with-generics
but it does not answer my question. I do not have a list or arrylist. My T generic  can be any class

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I provide a class name
i.e. className: Class
Although  I used genric, when somebody wants to use my API and call getValue the  type is known, and he can provide the class name to the get value method.

```
class JsonFeatureFlag<T>(
    key: String,
    @StringRes nameResId: Int,
    category: DevOptionCategory,
    val defaultValue: T
): FeatureFlagV2<T>(key, nameResId, category) {


     fun getValue(className: Class<T>): T {
        val json = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().getString(key)
        return try {
            Gson().fromJson(json, className)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            reportInvalidJson(json)
            defaultValue
        }
    }
```